# Заменить точку на запятую

Tags: php

В выводе пишет например 1.25 и 10, а мне нужно с запятой 12,25 и 10,00

как это сделать?

```
$bet = $row['sum'];
$win = $row['win_summa'];
$coef = $win / $bet;
```

Comment: И как же из 1.25 может получиться 12.25?

Answer (score 1):

**[number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)** - Форматирует число с разделением групп

```
number_format ( float $num , int $decimals = 0 , string|null $decimal_separator = "." , string|null $thousands_separator = "," ) : string
```

- **num** - Форматируемое число.
- **decimals** -Устанавливает число знаков после запятой. Если 0, decimal_separator опускается в возвращаемом значении.
- **decimal_separator** - Устанавливает разделитель дробной части.
- **thousands_separator** - Устанавливает разделитель тысяч.

---

```
$number = 1234.56;

// английский формат (по умолчанию)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// французский формат
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// английский формат без разделителей групп
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Comment: Формат - это хорошо, но из `1.25` сделать `12.25` ему не по силам.

Comment: @Qwertiy думаю он опечатался

Comment: Ладно, убедил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy ой да ладно не по силам `number_format(1.25, 2, "2.", "")`

Comment: Прикольно, не ожидал))) На всякий случай проверил xD https://ideone.com/UM6Do1

Comment: Спасибо за помощь конечно, но я уже решил проблему год назад :)

Comment: @MarmelARYT этот ответ и был опубликован год назад. Причём в тот же день, что и вопрос. Можно галочку ткнуть)